# Ubuntu 12.04 LTS: Changing Mysql root Password

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, password

I did an upgrade from 10.04 to 12.04 today. I wanted to access MySQL afterwards, but I've forgot the root password... So I tried some guides from the net but none is working for me. Im not even sure which MySQL-Version is installed right now:

```
root:~# apt-cache show mysql-server | grep Version
Version: 5.5.38-0ubuntu0.12.04.1
Version: 5.5.22-0ubuntu1
```

root:~# dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.5 <- Did not work - server not installed. But it is working fine...

Who can help?

Answer (score 1):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/resetting-permissions.html

1. Stop mysqld and restart it with the `--skip-grant-tables` option. This enables anyone to connect without a password and with all privileges. Because this is insecure, you might want to use `--skip-grant-tables` in conjunction with `--skip-networking` to prevent remote clients from connecting.
2. Connect to the mysqld server with this command: `mysql`
3. Issue the following statements in the mysql client. Replace the password with the password that you want to use. `UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('MyNewPass') WHERE User='root'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`